# How to filter view elements for specific user?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, authorization

I am building simple social network app. I am using .NET core 2.0 and Identity to handle users. I have Role Authentication for both View and Controller. I have the following problem: Every user have Profile page and the user can upload picture(avatar). However, I can go and upload pictures for other users by accessing their profile. I did CRUD authorization for the Profile model so If you are not the owner of that record you cant edit it, however I still can see the upload image form. Can I hide is somehow based on the Authenticated user and the profile url?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but generally, I think you're looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: I would give more information if needed. About the resource based authorization, i am thinking is this a resource ? its a form tag. I was thinking more of a some kind of If statement that checks if the user is in their own profile. I know you can say `@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "PolicyName")).Succeeded)` but many users can have the same policy. My question is: is there a way to filter HTML elements based on user identity. If resource-based authentication is the key please help me understand how an form is resource?

Comment: How about comparing current user Id and the profile's userId (assume you have the userId in profile url) in your action, then pass the result to view with `@if(@ViewBag.result)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Xing. I kinda did the same thing. In the controller which is taking attribute ID checks the current user ID and the ID from the profile that its returning. Then I assign a viewbag item that tells me if this is the same user. I am not sure if this is 100% the best way to do it, but it works :) Thank you all.